# Tail Recursive Combinations

Tags: f#, tail-recursion

I have this code:

```
    let rec combinations acc listC = 
        match listC with
        | [] -> acc 
        | h::t ->
            let next = [h]::List.map (fun t ->  h::t) acc @ acc
            combinations next t
```

It looks tail recursive, but I keep getting stack overflows with it. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: you get stack-overflows where? FSI?, Mono? - You enabled the TCO?

Comment: Can  you show IL generated from this code?

Comment: this should be tail-recursive - most likely you either did not enable TCO or the problem is somewhere else - btw: how big is the list you start with? Maybe you should consider switching to seqs

Comment: I've used it in two places, one as an .xll with ExcelDNA, and second as server side function in websharper (debug)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`combinations` is tail recursive.  Your problem is with the `@` operator.  Appending a list with it iterates the whole list, so as your `acc` becomes large, you will get a SO.

You can see [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3846), that the `@` operator is not tail recursive.  The non-optimized version looks like: `let rec (@) x y = match x with [] -> y | (h::t) -> h :: (t @ y)`.

To get around this problem, there are a couple of options:

1. If you don't care about order, you could write a tail-recursive method to prepend the result like this:

   `let rec prepend lst1 lst2 =
     match lst1 with
     | [] -> lst2
     | head::tail -> prepend tail (head::lst2)`

> ```
> > prepend [1;2;3;4] [5;6;7;8];; 
> val it : int list = [4; 3; 2; 1; 5; 6; 7; 8]
> ```

2. If you care about order, you could write a method to first reverse the list and then prepend it.  The drawback of this, of course, is that it will require twice as much memory since you are allocating an additional list to hold the reversed version of the original list.  You can reuse the previous function to write something like this:

   `let prepend2 lst1 lst2 =
       prepend (prepend lst1 []) lst2`

> ```
> > prepend2 [1;2;3;4] [5;6;7;8];; 
> val it : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8]
> ```

Comment: Interesting, I'll test that out. Thanks for the help