# F# map a seq to another seq of shorter length

Tags: f#

I have a sequence of strings like this (lines in a file)

```
[20150101] error a
details 1
details 2
[20150101] error b
details
[20150101] error c
```

I am trying to map this to a sequence of strings like this (log entries)

```
[20150101] error a details 1 details 2
[20150101] error b details
[20150101] error c
```

I can do this in an imperative way (by translating the code I would write in C#) - this works but it reads like pseudo-code because I have omitted the referenced functions:

```
let getLogEntries logFilePath =  
    seq {
        let logEntryLines = new ResizeArray<string>()

        for lineOfText in getLinesOfText logFilePath do                        
            if isStartOfNewLogEntry lineOfText && logEntryLines.Any() then
                yield joinLines logEntryLines
                logEntryLines.Clear()  
            logEntryLines.Add(lineOfText)  

        if logEntryLines.Any() then
            yield joinLines logEntryLines             
    }
```

Is there a more functional way of doing this?

I can't use `Seq.map` since it's not a one to one mapping, and `Seq.fold` doesn't seem right because I suspect it will process the entire input sequence before returning the results (not great if I have very large log files). I assume my code above isn't the ideal way to do this in F# because it's using `ResizeArray<string>`.

Comment: Actually `Seq.fold` should be lazy and work just fine. It's just awkward to use for this kind of accumulating work.

Comment: Have you looked at `Seq.choose`?

Comment: @mydogisbox `Seq.choose` seems to be a combination of `map` and `filter`, I need a combination of `map` and `fold`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much in-built in `Seq` that is going to help you, so you have to roll your own solution. Ultimately, parsing a file like this involves iterating and maintaining state, but what F# does is encapsulate that iteration and state by means of computation expressions (hence your use of the `seq` computation expression).

What you've done isn't bad but you could extract your code into a generic function that computes the *chunks* (i.e. sequences of strings) in an input sequence without knowledge of the format. The rest, i.e. parsing an actual log file, can be made purely functional.

I have written this function in the past to help with this.

```
let chunkBy chunkIdentifier source = 
    seq { 
        let chunk = ref []
        for sourceItem in source do
            let isNewChunk = chunkIdentifier sourceItem
            if isNewChunk && !chunk <> [] then 
                yield !chunk
                chunk := [ sourceItem ]
            else chunk := !chunk @ [ sourceItem ] 

        yield !chunk
    }
```

It takes a `chunkIdentifier` function which returns true if the input is the start of a new chunk.

Parsing a log file is simply a case of extracting the lines, computing the chunks and joining each chunk:

```
logEntryLines |> chunkBy (fun line -> line.[0] = '[')
    |> Seq.map (fun s -> String.Join (" ", s))
```

By encapsulating the iteration and mutation as much as possible, while creating a reusable function, it's more in the spirit of functional programming.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer because I can see the F# team using mutable state and iteration in the implementation of other functions in the Seq module
https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L825

Comment: As I noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30685000/901059 , `@` is not tail recursive, so this solution may SO on large inputs.

Answer (score 3):

In general, when there is no built-in function that you can use, the functional way to solve things is to use recursion. Here, you can recursively walk over the input, remember the items of the last chunk (since the last `[xyz] Info` line) and produce new results when you reach a new starting block. In F#, you can write this nicely with sequence expressions:

```
let rec joinDetails (lines:string list) lastChunk = seq {
  match lines with
  | [] -> 
      // We are at the end - if there are any records left, produce a new item!
      if lastChunk <> [] then yield String.concat " " (List.rev lastChunk)
  | line::lines when line.StartsWith("[") ->
      // New block starting. Produce a new item and then start a new chunk
      if lastChunk <> [] then yield String.concat " " (List.rev lastChunk)
      yield! joinDetails lines [line]
  | line::lines ->
      // Ordinary line - just add it to the last chunk that we're collection
      yield! joinDetails lines (line::lastChunk) }
```

Here is an example showing the code in action:

```
let lines = 
  [ "[20150101] error a"
    "details 1"
    "details 2"
    "[20150101] error b"
    "details"
    "[20150101] error c" ]

joinDetails lines []
```

Comment: thanks, I think changing my code into a recursive function has made it better, although the result doesn't look quite as nice as the code in the sample - I have a `Seq<string>` rather than a `list`, so I can't do the `head::tail` matching - I have to pass an `IEnumerator<string>` argument and use .Current and .MoveNext() instead

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, another two variants:

```
let lst = ["[20150101] error a";
           "details 1";
           "details 2";
           "[20150101] error b";
           "details";
           "[20150101] error c";]

let fun1 (xs:string list) = 
    let sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(xs.Head) 
    xs.Tail

    |> Seq.iter(fun x -> match x.[0] with
                         | '[' -> sb.Append("\n" + x) 
                         | _   -> sb.Append(" "  + x) 
                         |> ignore)
    sb.ToString()

lst  |> fun1 |> printfn "%s"

printfn "";

let fun2 (xs:string list) =  
    List.fold(fun acc (x:string) -> acc + 
                                    match x.[0] with| '[' -> "\n"  | _   -> " " 
                                    + x) xs.Head xs.Tail 

lst |> fun2 |> printfn "%s"
```

Print:

```
[20150101] error a details 1 details 2
[20150101] error b details
[20150101] error c

[20150101] error a details 1 details 2
[20150101] error b details
[20150101] error c
```

Link: 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/3KcIwv

Comment: This is nicely functional but I think it builds up the entire result into memory, which might run into performance problems when parsing large log files. I wasn't very specific in my question (maybe I should edit it?), but the reason why I mentioned 'map a seq to another seq of shorter length' is that most of the parsed data will be filtered out right after parsing, so processing it using sequences means unneeded data can be discarded straight away.